# Chrome Dev-Tools Electron Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools, undefined, typeerror

I am learning to scrape electron apps and am getting strange behavior on the console when attempting to iterate over an array. If I issue the exact same commands on one element in the array manually everything works as expected, but I get an Uncaught TypeError when using a for loop.

```
> var models = manager.getInstance().collection.models
undefined
> models.length
2378
> var attributes = models[0].attributes
undefined
> var resource = attributes.getResource()
undefined
> resource
//outputs object tree
> resource.idle.length
14
> models[0].attributes.getResource().idle.length
14
```

When iterating, however, any element's resource.idle.length will crash.

```
> var models = manager.getInstance().collection.models
undefined
> models.length
2378
> var data = new Array()
undefined
> for (n=0; n<models.length; n++;) {
     var attributes = models[n].attributes
     var resource = attributes.getResource()
     if (resource.idle.length > 0) {
          data.push(resource.idle)
     }
  }
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Is this an issue with the electron app? Having dug around in the console and code a bit, it seems like a huge mess. Sometimes when I create a var or just query the console, it will output undefined, but if I wait for a sec and issue the exact same command in the console, it will not come back undefined.

Did I mess something up here, or is this an async/threading issue? Is the `for loop` running too fast for the references to the object to get assigned in time for the next command? If so, what are good techniques for handling this?

Comment: The error evidently occurs in a different place: `resource.idle.length`.

Comment: Definitely your models are undefined, so calling length on it throws error. Please show in your manager class, how you are getting collection/models?